# Error propagation into the solution of an ODE

Tags: partial-derivative, error-propagation

In the simplest case, I have

$$f(x) = a x^2 + b x^3, $$

where $a$ and $b$ have some error $\Delta a$ and $\Delta b$ respectively. I know that in the absence of error, the equation

$$\frac{df}{dx} = 0$$

has solutions at $x = 0$ and $x = - \frac{2 a}{3b}$. How do I find the changes to the minima in the presence of the errors $\Delta a$ and $\Delta b$?

EDIT: And now, in general, I have an expansion

$$f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N) = \sum\limits_{i} \alpha_{i} x_i + \sum\limits_{i} \sum\limits_j \beta_{ij} x_i x_j + \sum\limits_{i} \sum\limits_j \sum\limits_k \gamma_{ijk} x_i x_j x_k + ...$$

up to sixth order, where the coefficients $\alpha_i, \beta_{ij}, \gamma_{ijk}, ...$ in principle could have their own errors $\Delta \alpha_i, \Delta \beta_{ij}, \Delta \gamma_{ijk}, ...$.

Does there exist some general expression (of course depending on the functional form of $f$) that the solutions to

$$\frac{df}{dx_k} = 0, \,\,\mathrm{for}\,\,k = 1, 2, ... N$$

can be found with the influence of the errors?

Answer (score 0):

$x=0$ is still $x=0$ after a change in $a$ or $b$.
$$ - \frac{2(a+\Delta a)}{3(b + \Delta b} = - \frac{2a}{3b} + \frac{2(a \Delta b - b \Delta a)}{3 b (b + \Delta b)}$$
If $\Delta b$ is small compared to $b$, the term on the right is approximately
$$ \dfrac{2 a}{3b^2} \Delta b - \dfrac{2}{3b} \Delta a$$

Comment: And, in general? I've edited the question to reflect really what I'm after.

Comment: You could notice that the above expressions bear much resemblance to partial derivatives with respect to the parameters. This is no coincidence, John Taylor's error analysis text book visits this type of stuff.